# MFC How to notify the document is changed (and display the *)

Tags: c++, mfc

I am used to, when I change a document for instance in Microsoft Word, it gets a `*` near the filename and the application automatically knows I should save the document.

How can I replicate this behaviour in MFC and notify my Document class of these changes, so that the app automatically knows the doc needs saving?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To notify the document that it is modified, you should use the [`CDocument::SetModified`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/570zcz2s.aspx) method, and to query whether it is modified, you can use the [`CDocument::IsModified`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/653zfaf3.aspx). For the view, [`CView::OnUpdate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w1z3te7e.aspx) is called when the document is updated.

Comment: However, from my research it is not simple to display the asterisc notifying that the document has been changed. Am I correct?

Answer (score 2):

A bit late, but I just had to do the same thing.

Once you set the document's modified flag, change the title. Here's an example:
            m_pDoc->SetModifiedFlag(bChanged);

```
        CString stTitle = m_pDoc->GetTitle();
        if (stTitle.Left(2) == _T(" *"))) {
            stTitle = stTitle.Left(stTitle.GetLength() - 2);
        }

        if (bChanged) {
            stTitle += _T(" *");
            m_pDoc->SetTitle(stTitle);
        }
        else {
            m_pDoc->SetTitle(stTitle);
        }
```